# Read csv and Print matched text using Jenkins declarative Pipeline Script

Tags: python-3.x, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

currently Im working on jenkins declarative pipeline scripting it would be great if I can get some help with the scripting below.
I have 10 CSV files in a location. I want to open each file and find the "failureMessage" in each CSV and print the same in console output along with file name.
I below example, File1 having failureMessage "Test failed: text expected to equal" in two places. File2 having in one place. File3 doesnt have any failure message.

Input CSV files

### File 1:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1583830716746,1202,HTTP Request- Authorization TC01,200,OK,ZH 1-1,text,true,,530,354,1,1,1202,0,1124
1583830717967,59,ID_001_Wrong_PNR,500,Internal Error,ZH 1-1,text,false,"Test failed: text expected to equal",322,1023,1,1,58,0,0
1583830718034,149,ID_002_Wrong_PAX ,200,Ok,ZH 1-1,text,true,,471,1023,1,1,149,0,0
1583830720338,113,ID_019_mPax_mSeg_assign_Adult,200,Ok,ZH 1-1,text,false,"Test failed: boolen expected to equal",638,1807,1,1,113,0,0
1583830718456,106,ID_005_sPax_sSeg_assign_Adult_Only_Mandatory_Fields_and_flightNo_with_leading_zeros_Revenue,
1583830718664,123,ID_008_sPax_sSeg_change_Adult_Revenue,200,Ok,ZH 1-1,text,false,"Test failed: string to equal",407,1047,1,1,123,0,0
```

### File2:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1583830716746,1202,HTTP Request- Authorization TC01,200,OK,ZH 1-1,text,true,,530,354,1,1,1202,0,1124
1583830717967,59,ID_001_Wrong_PNR,500,Internal Error,ZH 1-1,text,false,"Test failed: text expected to equal",322,1023,1,1,58,0,0
```

My jenkins job console output should be something like:

```
File1 -  Test failed: text expected to equal
         Test failed: boolen expected to equal
File2 -  Test failed: string to equal
```

No need to print file3 as there are no errors.

I just started with below pipline script:

```
if (fileExists("/home/ec2-user/test/_Tests_1.csv"))
{
              echo ' MyCSV.csv found'
              readFile("/home/ec2-user/test/Tests_1.csv").split('\n').each { line, count -> def fields = line.split(',')
                             for(String item: fields) {
                                           println item

                                           }
                             }
} else {echo 'csv Not found. Failing.'}
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Please do wrap your sample of input and expected output into CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thanks for Reply. i added code tags in my above question. Please advise.